# Include .aar library module logs into Android application file logger?

Tags: android, logging

Is it possible to access log messages from 3rd party library aar modules somehow and append them when writing a customized file logger?

My purpose with the file logger is to be able to send a log file from the application in case of strange behavior.
In this case one of my aar libraries includes important information that I want to include in the file logger.

**Details**

- Library (.aar) logs to android.util.Log

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you use the `logcat` command to retrieve logs ?

Here is an example to send logs by email

```
public static void sendLog(Context context) {
       try {
           String fileName = "logcat_" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".txt";
           File outputFile = new File(context.getExternalCacheDir(), fileName);

           @SuppressWarnings("unused")
           Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("logcat -v time -f " + outputFile.getAbsolutePath());

           Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
           emailIntent.setType("plain/text");
           emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Android Log");
           emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "See attached log file");
           emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, FileProvider.getUriForFile(context, "com.yourapplicationid.fileprovider", outputFile));
           context.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent , "Send email..."));
       } catch (Exception e) {
           Log.e(TAG, "Exception when sending log: " + e.getMessage());
       }
   }
```

You need to specify a `FileProvider` in your Manifest :

```
    <provider
            android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="com.yourapplicationid.fileprovider"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/file_paths" />
    </provider>
```

And the XML file path

```
<paths>
    <external-cache-path
        name="external_cache"
        path="." />
</paths>
```

More information here : https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/logcat

Comment: To get Brunos example to work you would need to change "Uri.fromFile(outputFile))" to FileProvider.getUriForFile(context, "com.yourapplicationid.fileprovider", outputFile) and add a manifest entry